# STARTTLS issue when using google as the smtp server when using javamail

Tags: java, debian, jakarta-mail, dotcms

I use the Java based CMS dotCMS and I want to use google as the smtp server. I used the config as described in the dotCMS docs: http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/mail-configuration.

My config looks like this:

```
    <Resource
            name="mail/MailSession"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.debug="true"
            mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
            mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
            mail.smtp.auth="true"
            mail.smtp.port="465"
            mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
            mail.smtp.user="[my username]"
            mail.password="[my pwd]"
            username="[my username]"
            password="[my pwd]"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
     />
```

When I call the `$mailer.sendEmail` method I get an error back:

"Unable to Send Message: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c7sm25357283wjb.19 - gsmtp".

I also tried port `587`, but that did not help either.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  I'm using dotcms 2.5.6. running on debian 7.8 (wheezy)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need the [socketFactory setting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

You also shouldn't need the port setting.

Try setting mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true.  If that doesn't work, try setting mail.transport.protocol=smtps and change all the mail.smtp.* settings to mail.smtps.*.

The [Gmail entry in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) might be useful.

If none of that works, post the JavaMail debug output.

Comment: Hey Bill. Thanks for the tip. I'll test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 2 factor authentication set up in google?  I think this might prevent the authentication from happening.